# Caching JPQL query in L2 ehcache for JPA/hibernate/Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa, jpql

I set up second level cache in persistence.xml and configured each entity that needs to be cached as below:

persistence.xml:

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
 </properties>
```

Entities:

`@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)`

I have a JPQL query that has all of its entities that it references marked as cacheable and somehow I am hitting the database all the time rather getting it from cache.

Currently ehcache.xml has the following:

```
<defaultCache eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="100000"
    overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>


   <cache
        name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
```

How can I get the JPQL query to hit the cache instead? It seems that straight hibernate queries have this setCacheable but nothing like this in JPQL..

Any help appreciated.

Greg

Comment: Have you been able to get any query to work with the cache, JPQL or a Hibernate query?

Comment: I am using JPQL as the first query to test. So the answer is no because this is the first query I tried. I propably should run a simple query by primary key and see if that hits the cache as my first testing query loads three related entities. My feeling is that there may be something wrong with my ehcache.xml config.

Comment: The config is usually pretty standard, looks ok to me. Getting caching rigged up can take a little time, I've had better luck using `NamedQueries` when trying to cache queries. Not always an option but work well when you can use'm.

Comment: One thing to check is in your jpa-context.xml do you have this in there `<cache:annotation-driven />`